# How do I switch windows with Watir and parse that window with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, browser, html-parsing, nokogiri, watir-webdriver

I'm using the Watir webdriver to go to a website and pop up all relevant links on that website. I then want to parse those popup windows using Nokogiri.

```
via: searchablefile = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.window(:title, /detail/).html)
```

This doesn't work. How can I create a Nokogiri HTML page of a popup window?

The problem doesn't seem to be my reference. When I use the following code, it does work:

```
 browser.window(:title, /detail/).close
```

Comment: Please share link to the page and more relevant code.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What happens (eg is there an exception)?

Comment: We need more information. See http://sscce.org.